# Python - namespace conflict if deployed to two different paths

Tags: python, namespaces, python-packaging

I have a top level namespace, working like an organization namespace. Let's name that `myorg`, where it's `__init__.py` looks like this :

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

This is being deployed under `/opt` where our Python lives, along with some developed python libraries - let's say `mylib` .

So on a Python2.7 interpreter this works

```
>>> import myorg
>>> import myorg.mylib
```

Apart from the libraries, we have some client code that gets deployed elsewhere in the system, in `/bb/bin`. For example for `clientA` I can have :

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/bb/bin')
>>> import clientA
```

and this works.

However, due to how our code is structured, we share the same namespace `myorg` - so `clientB` is also under `myorg` and there is a `/bb/bin/myorg/__init__.py` as well, with the same contants as the one in the `/opt` path.

Question is :

why this one works -

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/bb/bin')
>>> import myorg.clientB
```

but this one doesn't :

```
>>> import myorg # import from /opt location
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/bb/bin')
>>> import myorg.clientB # it should find the module under myorg in /bb/bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named clientB
```

This also does not work :

```
>>> import myorg.mylib
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0,'/bb/bin') # Adding the /bb/bin path first
>>> import myorg.clientB
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named clientB
```

So, it's like the `myorg` namespace, if imported from the `/opt` then it will always try and find the modules under there.

Why is that? Can someone explain how to fix that issue and why that is happening?

I also dont understand why prepending that `/bb/bin` to my path does not make it work.

**TL;DR**

My intended behaviour or what I was hoping for is :

- search in the `/opt/` for the module
- if not found go to other e.g. `/bb/bin`

This works on first case, but it seems if `myorg` has been imported from `/opt` then it only looks for modules inside there.

Comment: In both cases it looks like you're trying to do `myorg.clientB` *after* already importing `myorg`. Have you tried doing instead `import myorg as something_else` and *then* doing `sys.path.append('/bb/bin') and `import myorg.clientB`, to make the namespaces not conflict?

Comment: You might also be able to use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) to get around this issue - specifically, `find_loader()`, which should take a filepath that you can directly point at the module you want to load

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy based on the other comments that should work, but I am still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's because "myorg" is already loaded - python loads modules/packages only once. If you load myorg (from /opt) first (or any sub-module as Python loads all "steps" of the import), then any myorg.something will be relative to that.

Can you try `import as`? [PEP describing it](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/).

If I understand how python works, this should work:

```
import myorg as whateveryouwant # import from /opt location
import sys
sys.path.append('/bb/bin')
import myorg.clientB
```

**EDIT:**
Noticed your comment that it doesn't work. :(

You can also try just appending `/bb/bin/myorg` and then importing just `clientB` instead of `myorg.clientB`. It's ugly but should work.